# jquery datepicker intercept format error

Tags: jquery, string, text, datepicker

I'm trying to figure out how to allow an incorrect value and automatically format it for the right value.

For example, if you enter 1 jun 2013, this value would not be permitted because the 'j' is not capitalized. Is there a way I can intercept the value as text (onBlur) and change the 'j' to a capital value?

The problem is, I'm getting an error before I can retrieve the raw value of the input. I'm not sure at which point I will be able to retrieve the value before it hits an error (from it not being able to parse the date).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your answers. I think I wasn't too clear on my problem.

After some time, I managed to figure out what I'm looking for. My solution is below:

```js
$("input.datepicker").datepicker({
...
})
.blur(function() {
var patt = new RegExp("[A-Z]");
var patt2 = new RegExp("[a-z]")
var text = $("input.datepicker").val();

if(!text.match(patt)) {
    var pos = text.search(patt2);
    var char = text.charAt(pos).toUpperCase();
    var correctedDate = text.replace(patt2, char);
    $("input.datepicker").val(correctedDate);
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting the date to be entered in the same format every time, you can write a function that will split your input by spaces, and then check to see if each piece is a number or not when run through `parseInt()`, and if not, then capitalize it.

```
function formatDate(date) {
  var dateElements = date.split(" ");
  var formattedDate = "";

  for (var i=0; i < dateElements.length; i++) {
    var dateElement = dateElements[i];

    if (isNaN(parseInt(dateElement))) {
      dateElement = dateElement.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + dateElement.slice(1);
    }
    formattedDate += dateElement + " ";
  }
  return formattedDate.trim();
}

var formattedDate = formatDate("1 jun 2013");
alert(formattedDate);
```

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zaknotzak/wHyQD/2/).

Comment: In this case, I don't think I can retrieve the date object because when it tries to retrieve the date, it throws an error because of the 'j'.

Comment: You should be able to get the value with `$(".datepicker").val();`

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the wrongly typed date selected in the datepicker, you might find the following useful:

```
<body>

<form>
<input type="text" name="date" id="date"/>
</form>
<script>
$("#date").datepicker({constrainInput:false,dateFormat:"d M yy",onClose:function(picker,str) { $("#date").datepicker("setDate","yourdate in correct format"); } });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems this only works if the date is chosen using the calendar. In my scenario, the user types in the incorrect date.

Comment: When focusing the text field the calendar is shown. Onblur of the textfield onClose is called no matter what as of jquery-ui-1.10.1